# In Xcode 4.5, why does Instruments no longer show my app under eliglible targets to instrument?

Tags: xcode, xcode-instruments

Here's what happened:

1. I connected my iPad via USB to my devbox.
2. I fired up Xcode 4.5, then opened Xcode>Open Developer Tool>Instruments.
3. I chose my iPad under Choose Target.
4. I then selected a template -- let's say Time Profiler for the sake of discussion.
5. I then chose my app (already loaded on my iPad) as the target from All Processes>Choose Target...
6. I recorded the instrumented app for a while, then stopped recording.
7. I quit Instruments.

Next, I restarted my Mac.  I restarted Xcode 4.5, and Instruments.
I followed steps above to instrument my app.  But guess what?  My
app is nowhere to be found under All Processes>Choose Target...?

I tried this with another app to see if something unusual had happened
with my first app during my first profiling session.  The same thing
happened with the second app!  Neither app now appears under the list
of eligible apps that I can target when setting up an Instruments recording.

QUESTIONS:

## 1 Isn't there some simple way to reset Instruments to its virgin state?

## 2 What is going on?  In particular, where does Instruments archive its profiling data?

I haven't read the Instruments documentation, so apologies up front.  If someone
has a quick answer, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

The posted questions remain.  I was able to work around this issue
by firing up my app on a live iPad, and then connecting Instruments
to my app by selecting: All Processes>Attach To Process>My.App

But if my app is not already started, Instruments simply does not
find a reference to it (after following the steps listed above).